# Only commit changes to Firestore on app/widget close

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

As Firestore charges by the read/write, it would be super helpful to keep the changes in memory during the session and only commit them when the user exists either the entire app or a specific section. Is there a way to do that in a Flutter web application?

Answer (score 1):

I think one problem with this approach is that the user might just close the tab including your app. In this case, you have no time to send your data to Firestore.

This aside, you could use packages like [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive_flutter) to store your documents offline and later run a function to add the data to Firestore later.

You also have 50k reads and 20k writes for free with Firebase, which is sufficient for smaller apps. If you exceed this limit, your app is probably big enough to earn money with it anyway.